# Server-side React rendering without Babel require hook

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs, server-side-rendering, react-server

Is there any good way to use server-side rendering without Babel `require` hook?

Right now I'm using it to compile `jsx` on server and for ES6 module imports/exports (since they are not yet supported in `Node.js`). I think I can ditch imports/exports for `require`, but I'd like to stay with `jsx`. The main problems that I encounter with require hook are debugging and slow server start.

I know that some people use gulp to load source-maps to solve the debugging issue, but it seems like an overkill for me.